# Definite article or no definite article before "Americans" in this sentence from "The Adventure of English"

Tags: grammaticality, definite-articles

> [The Adventure of English](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=vmshAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT20&dq=The+Adventure+of+English&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=k1KCVN6AOe_hsASHz4KwCg&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=The%20Adventure%20of%20English&f=false), page 286, reads "The Americans are more polite about the English than the English are about Americans"

I wouldn't use the definite article before "Americans" in this sentence, and I can't understand why it is used at the beginning of the sentence but not at the end. Are both cases correct (using and omitting)?

For clarity: the sentence is the beginning of a paragraph that goes on: .... "The British feared that "their" English had been taken from them; that its new owners were not looking after it as deserved; and a deeper fear that they were at the cutting edge now: it was not the British who propelled the adventure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, both uses are correct.

Part of it is stylistic. *The* Americans somehow sounds better than *Americans* at the beginning of the sentence. Part of this is that *The* Americans goes well with the two uses of *the* English. But why switch to *Americans* with the zero-article?

Here lies the difference between 'Americans' with or without 'the'.

'The Americans' refers to all Americans, as in 'The Americans as a people' or 'the American people.' Thus, it is equivalent to 'The English.' By contrast *Americans* means 'Americans in general' and does not have to refer to all Americans.

Answer (score 2):

The author uses 'the English' (where 'English' is an adjective that stands in for the noun 'Englishmen'), but 'Americans' is a noun. In this context, the definite article is required before 'English'. It is not required before 'Americans'.